# The number of integers $n$ with $100<n<200$ such that $8$ divides $n^2-n-2$ and $27$ divides $n^2+2n-3$.

Tags: number-theory

The number of positive integers that $n$ can take in between the range $100$ to $200$.

I tried a lot using the prime factorization method but no use.

Comment: can you explain it more clearly using the chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: can you say the exact answer and also the values of n please

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

$$n^2-n-2=(n-2)(n+1)$$

$$n^2+2n-3=(n+3)(n-1)$$

As $n+1-(n-2)=3,n-2,n+1$ are of opposite parity, exactly one of them must be divisible by $8$

As $n+3-(n-1)=4,$  exactly one of them must be divisible by $27$

Now use [CRT](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html) for all $2\cdot2$ possible cases.

Comment: +1.  Exhaustive enumeration only takes a minute or so, also, if OP doesn't want to learn CRT. :-P

Answer (score 0):

What I want is just to find out a solution. I feel the one I have found is the only but I have not stopped to prove this.

The identities $$(8t+2)^2-(8t+2)-2=8(8t^2+3t)\\(27s+24)^2+2(27s+24)-3=27(27s^2+50s+23)$$ establish two parametrizations, respectively for the diophantine equations $$n^2-n-2=8y\\n^2+2n-3=27z$$

We have$$100\lt8t+2\lt 200\iff 13\le t\le 24$$ which corresponds with
$$n\in\{106,114,122,130,138,146,154,162,170,178,\color{red}{186},194\}$$

We have also$$100\lt 27s+24\lt 200\iff 3\le s\le 6$$ which corresponds with
$$n\in\{105,132,159,\color{red}{186}\}$$
In fact one has
$$(186)^2-186-2=\color{red}{8}\cdot4301\\(186)^2+2(186)-3=\color{red}{27}\cdot1295$$